# Json responseText empty and statusText as error

Tags: json, jquery, jsonp, jsonresult

From mvc 4 action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DoStuff(string str)
    {
        // Do some things

            Response.ContentType = "application/json;charset=utf-8";
            Response.StatusCode = someCondition == true ? HttpStatusCode.OK : HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

        return Json(
            new {
               object1 = 1,
               object2 = someArray[0],
               object3 = someArray[1],
               object4 = someValue == 4 ? 1 : 0
            }
        );
    }
```

In jquery ajax:

```
ajax({
    url: '/Ctrler/DoStuff/',
    data: { str: someString },
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json'
}).then(function (data) {
    var _response = $.parseJSON(data);
}, function (data) {
    var _response = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);
});
```

data.responseText is empty ("") and statusText is "error". It is not always happening. I have observed that it is happening randomly. Why?

Comment: Nothing happens randomly :) If you're getting errors from a request check the console. There is an error occurring on the server-side.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have catched the error in the ajax call using a try-catch and it says syntax error as a result of trying to parse json which responseText is empty and statusText is error. If nothing happens randomly why executing the same action in the controller x times, a lot of times is working and then there is one that is failing?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan console says: SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network error 0x2ee2, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002ee2.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is already being converted to an object from JSON, so you do not need to parse it again. Try this:

```
ajax({
    url: '/Ctrler/DoStuff/',
    data: { str: someString },
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json'
}).then(function (data) {
    // use data here...
    alert(data.object1);
}, function () {
    alert('request failed');
});
```

Comment: I have done your solution and data.object1 is undefined but data.responseText contains the json object, so I was parsing it as json. However there are times that the same code is failing as data.responseText is empty.

Comment: I forgot to post a piece of code in the thread. Please, see my post updated: I need to return a json object plus a http status code.

Comment: It seems like it is failing when debuggin from visual studio. Once deployed under a website it is not happening... I do not know why...

Comment: In my real case I have some ping tasks (action in controller) awaiting to be served. Those ping tasks has been executed by the indicated jquery-ajax call. So they are served one by one but last ping requests that are awaiting to be served seem to be aborted/cancelled then responseText is returned as empty for them and then it crashes. statusText is "error" and status is 0.